# Jenkins include file parameter and string parameter inside choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to include file/string parameters values inside choice parameter in jenkins?
Ex - I have a choice parameter called 'File' which has two values FILE01 and FILE02. If user chooses FILE01 I want other file/string/date parameters to show up, if he chooses FILE02 I want other file/string/date parameters to show up and build the job based on input.This parameters will be passed to ansible playbook. Is there any way to do it?

[Current fuzzy Parameters example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBsrp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to dynamically populate the string parameter from your choice parameter. Have you explored the usage of the ActiveChoice Reactive Parameter ? This could be a solution for your use-case.

More details here - https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/

Comment: I Have tried this its working I can dynamically populate for string and choice parameters using Formatted HTML with Active choice reactive reference parameter. I would need to include even file parameter here to upload an file dynamically,any idea?

Comment: Also, Based on selected choice parameter i need the string and other parameters also to change to different name, so that i can pass that to playbook that i am running,any thoughts on this?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your second question. Do you want to upload a file when FILE1 was chosen ? Ofcourse you can always create a case/switch inside a stage in your Jenkinsfile when FILE01 was chosen and upload the file while fetching it from wherever its hosted. But if you want to upload a file as a Jenkins parameter then you would have write a Groovy Script and test it. I wouldn't call it a recommended approach as you can safely do this as a stage in your Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Now to the other question to change the file name, you may also perform this as a stage in your jenkinsfile where you can change it to whatever name you need and then call your playbooks as a follow up stage. Hopefully this helps.